# All instances are launching in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am working to build an all in one small use case to demonstrate major compute resources integrated using terraform.
However, all my ec2 instances are launching into private subnets. I have tried multiple ways but seems like still something is missing.

A short version of demo repo is available at https://github.com/smustafa75/vpc_private_link

Please guide here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `network` module you have the following output:

```
output "public_net" {
  value = aws_subnet.tf_private_subnet.*.id
}
```

I believe you wanted to ouput this IDs of the public subnets (`aws_subnet.tf_public_subnet.*.id`) in this case.

You have the same output for the `private_net`, which I assume is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its fixed right away.